# loadVideoById() in YouTube's regular player (not chromeless)

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I have a YouTube's player in the webpage. I need to change the video played by this player dynamicaly.

This is (relatively) easy using YouTube's chromeless player. It has method [`loadVideoById()`](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html#loadVideoById) which works perfectly. The problem is, that the chromeless player doesn't have any controls (play/pause, etc.). The [regular YouTube player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Functions) has all this, but it doesn't have the `loadVideoById()` method.

Is there any way to include the controls of regular player into chromeless player, or to implement `loadVideoById()` method in the regular player?

Thanks.

Comment: WARNING: sometimes Google appends a `&ltr;` marker to the end of a YouTube ID (such as in search results page). if you accidentally copy it - this invisible character will give you 'Invalid Parameters' error when you try to use `loadVideoById()`. Use the cursor keys to make sure there's no invisible characters at the end of any Video IDs

Comment: also remember that on iOS you can't start a youtube video (or any HTML5 video) without explicitly clicking play. If you call `loadVideoById()` you must first check that the video is playing or it'll just go to a black box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do that, cause the calls in the "regular youtube player" have the VideoID in the URL instead as a parameter:

- Regular Video: http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer
- Chromeless: http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1

Instead of that you can easily create your own function that changes the Embbebed SWF, i mean, say that you are using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for the "Regular Player", then using [createSWF function](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.createSWF(attObj,_parObj,_replaceElemIdStr)) you will be able to replace the previous video for the actual one dynamically.

Hope this help you.

Comment: now "regular video player" has loadVidoeById and loadVideoByUrl options

Answer (score 3):

You can do this...

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#change_the_playing_video

Answer (score 2):

FYI there also a jQuery plugin that can do it for you, and provide you with a ton of controls!

<strike>http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin</strike>

https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin

Comment: This is so much easier! Why didn't I just think to look for a jQuery plugin in the first place?! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to use loadVideoByUrl() as an alternative to loadVideoByIdl() instead of using createSWF, you don't have to mess with the swfobject this way, it's a built-in function...just use the video ID to create a youtube swf url such as:  url="http://www.youtube.com/e/" + VIDEO_ID + "?enablejsapi=1&version=3" and submit using the loadVideoByUrl() function like this:  player.loadVideoByUrl(url)

That way you don't have to mess with the swfobject, it's spelled out here:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#loadVideoById

"player.loadVideoByUrl(mediaContentUrl:String, startSeconds:Number):Void
    Loads and plays the specified video.

```
    * The mediaContentUrl must be a fully qualified YouTube player URL in the format http://www.youtube.com/e/VIDEO_ID. In YouTube Data API video feeds, the url attribute of the <media:content> tag contains a fully qualified player URL when the tag's format attribute has a value of 5.
    * startSeconds accepts a float/integer and specifies the time from which the video should start playing. If startSeconds (number can be a float) is specified, the video will start from the closest keyframe to the specified time."
```